# Symfony 2 -> Composer and CloudControl

Tags: symfony, composer-php, cloudcontrol

I have a little problem to setup Symfony 2 on Cloudcontrol,

I followed the instructions and installed a Symfony 2 framework, changed the document root and so on.
Now when I try to push the changes to server server, it loads the dependencies from the composer.json and then it failed with a message :

> [RuntimeException]
>   Could not scan for classes inside "/srv/tmp/builddir/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

This file is a vendor package, loaded from composer.

I have the same effect with a default composer.json file from a sample project (SF2)

Localy it works very well!

Can some one give me a hint ?

Comment: Did you try pushing the code to a different deployment? Maybe something is wrong with the cache in this one.

Comment: Do you have a composer.phar in the root of your repository, if so what version is it?

Answer (score 14):

Got same error after setting "minimum-stability":"dev" and running composer update.

for unknown reason symfony/symfony (dev-master ...) kept failing to download from source thus was being loaded from cache.

what worked for me was a mix of previous answers:

```
$ rm -rf vendor/symfony
$ composer clearcache
$ composer install
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes I had to clean composer cache to remove strange errors, usually it's in

```
/home/user/.composer/cache
```

You can also try to update composer with

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

I hope it runs for you.

Comment: I had the same problem. I didn't have enough memory to update so my cache got stuck with bad data. Once I deleted the cache, it all started working again. For me, the cache was located at `.user/.composer` a simple `rm -rf /.user/.composer/cache` deleted it all for me. Then re-installing worked fine. to find the cache, try cd'ing to the root, then `find -name ".composer"`

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same error in my development directory.

What fixed it was :

```
$ rm -rf vendor/symfony
$ php composer.phar install
```

It reinstalled `symfony/symfony`, `symfony/icu`, `symfony/assetic-bundle`, `symfony/monolog-bundle` and `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` and now everything works !